# How do I install F-prot anti-virus without root privileges?

Tags: 12.04

How to install F-prot (anti-virus software)? I'd like a step by step answer. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.1.
It's a .tar.gz package.

Comment: This is impossible, unless you heavily hack the install script. You could _try_ installing `fakeroot`, then running `fakeroot ./install-f-prot.pl`, but that probably wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is imposibble because for any change you need be root .